# Subtract raw floating-point files elementwise, with a script?

Tags: command-line, floating-point, binaryfiles, raw-data

I have two files which are raw sequences of little-endian 32-bit floating-point values (with no crazy values like infinity, NaN, denormals etc.), and I want to produce their elementwise difference in a third file.

Now, I can write a small utility to do this with relative efficiently in pretty much any compiled language, but I was wondering if I could achieve the same more easily with a short script using common tools. My intuition says "no", since it's pretty "non-textual" work, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Since POSIX shell does not have any arithmetic, let alone floating point arithmetic, it's not exactly the right tool for the job. Provided you can turn the raw data into a string representation of floats, you could use a tool such as `bc` for the arithmetic. Is the binary format for the floats *IEEE float 32*, and do you know whether they are stored big-endian or little-endian?

Comment: @user1934428: They're little-endian. I suppose I could go through string representation with something like od and a lot of bc'ing, but that would probably be pretty slow.

Comment: If speed is really an issue, why are you even considering a non-compiled language? If you insist in doing it with POSIX shell only (and not, i.e., Ruby or Perl (as Shawn suggested in his answer) or something along this line), I would split the task into two subproblem: Turning the binary representation into a string, and then processing the string within the context of the shell. If speed is important, the easiest way would likely be a C-program.

Comment: @user1934428: 1. I might be on a system where a compiler is not installed, for example. Plus - being "an issue" is not really a binary thing. Or maybe I'm just curious. 2. I didn't say POSIX shell only...

Comment: @user1934428: I said "common tools". I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick `perl` script that'll do it (Takes the two files as command line arguments, writes to standard output):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $file1, "<:raw", $ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open $ARGV[0]: $!\n";
open my $file2, "<:raw", $ARGV[1] or die "Unable to open $ARGV[1]: $!\n";
binmode STDOUT, ":raw";

while (read($file1, my $s1, 4) == 4 && read($file2, my $s2, 4) == 4) {
    my $f1 = unpack "f<", $s1;
    my $f2 = unpack "f<", $s2;
    print pack("f<", $f1 - $f2);
}
```

The key here is [`pack`](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#pack-TEMPLATE%2CLIST) and `unpack`'s `"f<"` format to work with explicitly little-endian single precision floats (In the host systems' native format, normally IEEE754 on most typical hardware).

Comment: Preciously eclectic rubbish lister to the rescue :-)  Can I expect this to be fast enough to handle "decent-size" image (say, a million floats and up)?

Comment: @einpoklum Runs in under a second for a million floats on my decade-old computer in a quick test just now.